# improper integrals( very basic)

Tags: improper-integrals

[image]

I don't quite understand what it really means. Do it mean that $f(c_i)$ could be infinite and $dx$ is very small, so you can't determine what the *infinite$\times$very small* is?

Answer (score 2):

The point is that if the function is nice, then the difference between all the different $f(c_i)$ for all valid choices of $c_i$ are roughly the same. Therefore, for any given partition, if it is fine enough, changing $c_i$ to some other valid value makes very little change in the total sum.

However, if $f$ is unbounded, then you can choose $c_i$ that makes $f(c_i)$ as large as you want, which means that for any given partition, different choices of $c_i$ can make that sum be basically whatever you want. That is why the limit is not defined.

Comment: But even though $f(c_i)$ coule be as large as I want, but it's still multiplied  by very small difference of partition, I still have on control on making it whatever I want.

Comment: @whosit Not really. I am, for a second, ignoring the limit symbol and just looking at one specific partition. I have $\Delta x_i$ available, and it does not change. Therefore I can make not only $f(c_i)$ as big as I want by choosing $c_i$, I can make $f(c_i)\Delta x_i$ as big as I want. This means I can make the sum over that specific partition as big as I want. Only after that do I look at the $\lim$ operator and conclude that it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Take a specific example, say $\int_0^2\frac 1{(x-1)^2}dx$  One of the intervals will cover $1$. The definition says the sum must converge no matter how we choose the $c_i$ in that interval (and all the rest), but if we choose that $c$ to be $1$ the sum is not defined.  Even if we do not choose exactly $1$, we can choose it close enough to $1$ that the sum is enormous.  As the text says, that shows we have to do something more carefully.  Presumably the next paragraphs will show what that is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still don't get it. I can understand what we choose the c1 to be 1, which is not defined. But for $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(c_i)\Delta x\,$$    $f(c_i)$ is $\infty$ and $\Delta x$ is very small, what could it be when $\infty$*very small? it's hard to say by choosing c1, we could get the sum as large as we want

Comment: It comes down to the order of choosing the points.  In the basic definition, $\Delta x$ is chosen first, so $c$ can be chosen to make $f(c)$ larger than $\frac 1{\Delta x^2}$ so the product is large.  The limit your book will show you next puts a cap on how big $f(c)$ can be, then lets you choose $\Delta x$ to keep the product small.

Comment: $f(c_i)$ is large ($\infty$),  $\frac{1}{\Delta x^{2}}$ is also large($\infty$), how can we tell which one is larger? It is a little bit hard to choose a  $\infty$ larger than another $\infty$  The book didn't show how big $f(c_i)$ can be, it just gave an example.

Comment: I was choosing $c_i$ so $f(c_i)=\frac 1{\Delta x^2}$ so the product with $\Delta x$ is large.

Comment: em, maybe I got sth wrong in my mind. could you please tell me what's the limit of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty ,y\to 0}xy$$

Comment: There is no limit to this because you let both variables go simultaneously.  But $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\lim_{y \to 0} xy)=0$ because you do the $y$ limit first.

Comment: the product is large, we can  say the intergal must diverge(it should be divergent, but not always the case actually)